# Can't navigate the page in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have created addnewemployee.blade.php in the views folder. In routes, I have mentioned

```
 Route::get('/addnewemployee', function() {
        return view('addnewemployee');  
    });
```

As well as I have given the path in my `enter code here`home page like

```
   <a class="btn cus-button" href="{{url('/addnewemployee')}}"> Add New </a>
```

Once I click the add new button, 'addnewemployee' is added with my URL but it shows 404 not found.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Check path of your blade file once.

Comment: the path of the blade file is 
http://localhost:8080/asbury/resources/views/addnewemployee.blade.php
but in the previous project I didn't give exact path I just navigate it from public folder and that was working fine. now it's not working I don't know what the mistake is

Comment: If `addnewemployee.blade.php`is in `resources/views` then the above code should work perfectly.

Comment: The resources folder should not be available via URL, `/public` should be the document root. `http://localhost:8080/asbury/resources/views/addnewemployee.blade.php` sounds invalid. Have you set up your Laravel project correct?

Answer (score 0):

The `addnewemployee.blade.php` should be in hte `resources/views/addnewemployee.blade.php` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('/addnewemployee', function() {
        return view('addnewemployee');  
    })->name('addnewemployee');
```

```
<a class="btn cus-button" href="{{ route('addnewemployee') }}"> Add New </a>
```